# Как получить пинг бота в дискорде (discord.py)

Tags: python

Как получить пинг бота в дискорде (discord.py)
код команды (не мой код взял с сайта)

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong!')
    ms = (t.timestamp-ctx.message.timestamp).total_seconds() * 1000
    await ctx.send(t, new_content='Pong! Took: {}ms'.format(int(ms)))
```

Answer (score 3):

В discord есть параметр [latency](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.Client.latency), который показывает задержку протокола WebSocket в секундах. Чтобы вывести эту задержку можно воспользоваться: `bot.latency`. Минимально работающий пример:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@bot.command(pass_context=False)
async def пинг(ctx):
  # Вывод задержки в чат с помощью команды .пинг
  await ctx.send('Пинг: {0}'.format(bot.latency)) 

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Надеюсь информация помогла.